# Get-SPWeb with a cross domain url throws an excepton

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, spweb, cross-site

I want to migrate list items held in our dev sharepoint farm to  site collection hosted on our live farm. Ok I have RDPed onto the server and I am running ISE as administrator  *I do another account I used to install sharepoint that is slightly  more permissions I could try*

```
#SourceWebURL is the URL of the web which contains the source list
$SourceWebURL = "http://dev/sites/sourcelists"


#DestinationWebURL is the URL of the web in which you want to transfer your documents
$DestinationWebURL = "https://corporate.companydomain.com"



 #DestinationWebURL is the URL of the web in which you want to transfer your documents
 $sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL


 #THIS GIVES THE ERROR WHEN RUN FROM THE DEV Sever
 $dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL
```

> Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following
>   Id or Url: Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the
>   following Id or Url: https://corporate.companydomain.com. At
>   C:\dev\ps\Admin\CopyFilesAndFolders.ps1:34 char:9
>   + $dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb],
>   SPCmdletPipeBindException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb
>
> At C:\dev\ps\Admin\CopyFilesAndFolders.ps1:34 char:9
>   + $dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb],
>   SPCmdletPipeBindException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb

Now until we get a local site security  policy change on AD when I open "https://corporate.companydomain.com" on a browser, I am presented with a login dialog box 
so this may be a factor. Just wondered if anyone seen this or able to "RunAs"  Get-SPWeb to get passed the Login box.

Comment: Can You connect this site not by HTTPS?

Comment: Imho if 'Get-SPWeb' does not use web-services, You should launch it on host

Answer (score 1):

That will only work with the local instance or machines joined to same domain.  You can look at remoting but you need to configure it to work with non-domain machine.

For instance -

If you want run from Dev.com and connect to Prod.com you have to set your SharePoint servers on Prod to trust the machine in the Dev domain to run PowerShell command.  To add server to trusted host list you use this command.

```
 Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'server.dev.com'
```

There are some other requirements such as remote ports and if you will remote over HTTPS (I actually thing that is a reimbursement) you need to configure SSL certs. I'm quite sure there may be some other things that may trip you up such as exporting objects between sessions.

Alternatives are to use the API's and create a custom console app or call them from PowerShell.

Comment: Hi @Jesus ... interesting I hadn't thought of that. Got talking to Paul Hunt from #suguk on FB last night who concurs  with your last point so PS + CSOM  looks the way to go